# How to send an image via a POST request in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, https, swift4, flask-restful

```
func createPost(username: String, user_id: String, description: String, image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: Globals.root+"/amazing/image/post/here")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    //request.httpBody = .data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
        }
        if let data = data {
            do {
                let aaData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let ppData = aaData as? [String:Any] {
                    let u = ppData["username"] as! Bool
                    if u == true {
                        completion(true)
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I've been searching and searching for a valid answer and I haven't found any that pertains to Swift 4. I want to be able to send an image to my RESTful API without encoding it. How can one do that? Thanks in advance. : )

Comment: Use multipart form to send image along with other parameters. For multipart  use can use Alamofire.

Answer (score 1):

First off, given the fact you're sending username, and stuff along with image, it must be a multipart form (or some ugly BASE64 encoded JSON property).

Typically speaking, clean way to do this is upload image first via binary body post (as the image is the sole thing in transfer and is faster too), obtain the Id and reference it as a field.

Failing this, it's quite hard, how about using Moya + AlamoFire?

https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/598

An image is a binary object, and this not valid HTTP unless you either encode it via multipart form or wrap it JSON safe Base-64 (assuming you are using JSON)

Comment: Though that's a decent idea, at large volume it could screw up since you're finding an id of an image that was just posted. Personally, I rather send everything(image and it's meta-data) in one go. I've thought about using AlamoFire but I'm against it.

Comment: You only get the Id once it's posted, you start it first. Use the multi-part form with AlamoFire if you must, do you control the backend?

Comment: I wrote the back-end. I use Python + Flask.

Comment: I would recommend you either do multipart form or image upload + request send. Personally, I would go with image upload async, get a media Id and attach on success but it's your choice, just remember multipart forms can get messy, Flask will abstract this somewhat.

Comment: I've decided to use Alamofire. Do you know how to do this with it?

Comment: Use Moya on top to create the Restful services: https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/1219 read that as it should explain it better than I. If you do not wish to use multipart and wish to just send the image, its a lot easier and you just create an upload task with the body being the image Data from file.